# Get page by id and show read more

Tags: wordpress

What is the best way to show multiple pages in a Wordpress page.
I only want to show the text before the read more. The following code is displaying the whole content instead of only the read more.

```
        $args=array(
        'orderby' =>'parent',
        'order' =>'asc',
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'post__in' => array(9,24,33),
        );

        $page_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <?php while ($page_query->have_posts()) : $page_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="g320">
                 <?php the_content("Lees meer",true);?>

            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a global variable $more which enables / disables this feature for the_content() function. [Read more in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Overriding_Archive.2FSingle_Page_Behavior)

In your example, the solution would be like this:

```
$args=array(
        'orderby' =>'parent',
        'order' =>'asc',
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'post__in' => array(9,24,33),
        );

        $page_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <?php while ($page_query->have_posts()) : $page_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="g320">
                 <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
                 <?php the_content("Lees meer",true);?>

            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are displaying full content using the_content.
But you can display excerpt with [...] at the end of each post.
So change the_content to the_excerpt and check if this fits your needs.

Read more here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

As you can read in above link "By default, excerpt length is set to 55 words. To change excerpt length using excerpt_length filter, add the following code to functions.php file in your theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The excerpt function is cutting my post after 55 words. But, I want to cut the post, where i gave a <!-- more --> tag. :)